# Excel formula Help: Random sequence number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, random-number-generator

Would like to seek assistance for excel formula for difference between two or more numbers . In this sample if i put value randomly in cell **G2**  is there formula to put generate random number between **A2 and B2** that equal in G2?  (Difference between B and A) and **H2** generate random number of cells between **B2 and C2**? Thank you in advance, Any suggestions would be helpful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUlBZ.png

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. What you're asking is unclear. What is the relationship between the cells you mention? Can you tell us what you've tried so far? And what the expected result is?

Comment: Sorry for my question is unclear. For example i put number 28 in cell G2. Cell A2 and B2 creates random generate number that equal (difference between B2-A2) in 28. like 25 and 3, 14 and 14, 8 and 20 etc. Thank you

Comment: You still haven't told us where the problem is exactly. Also, if possible, it would be helpful if you could edit your question and post what formulas you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking.

In cell `A2`, put this formula:

`=RANDBETWEEN(1,G2)`

then in cell `B2`, put this formula:

`=G2 - A2`

That will generate a random pair of numbers in `A2` and `B2` whose sum is in `G2`.

You'll get a new pair of numbers every time you enter a number in G2, **or** you can get a new pair of numbers *without* changing `G2` by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>